# Create list of abbreviations

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to create something similar to `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` etc. What I've done so far:

```
\def\startloa#1
{
    \begingroup
        \begin{listofabbrv}{SPMD}
        \@input{\jobname.#1}
        \end{listofabbrv}
        \global\@nobreakfalse
    \endgroup
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}
{
    \@startloa{loa}
}

% abvr{abvr}{text}
\def\abvr#1#2
{
    \makeatletter
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\backslash item[#1] #2}
    \makeatother
}

\newwrite\tempfile

\begin{document}

    \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.loa

    \listofabbreviations

    \abvr{NULL}{/dev/null}

    \immediate\closeout\tempfile

\end{document}
```

The `\begin`/`\end{listofabbvr}` is predefined in the style I'm using, so I can't change it. Is it done this way:

```
\begin{listofabbrv}{SPMD}
    \item[NULL] /dev/null
\end{listofabbrv}
```

The main problems:

- The `\abvr` command does not work. The file output is:

  ```
  \delimiter "026E30F item[NULL] /dev/null
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  \item[NULL] /dev/null
  ```
- The command `\listofabbreviations` does not work. Is there something wrong with `\def\startloa`? A little snippet of the output log:

  ```
  ERROR:
  74  ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
  75  \@->\spacefactor 
  76                   \@m 
  77  l.133   \listofabbreviations
  78                             
  79  ! Missing $ inserted.
  --- x --- x ---
  ERROR:
  79  ! Missing $ inserted.
  80  <inserted text> 
  81                  $
  82  l.133   \listofabbreviations
  83                             
  84  ! Missing $ inserted.
  --- x --- x ---
  ERROR:
  84  ! Missing $ inserted.
  85  <inserted text> 
  86                  $
  87  l.134 
  88        
  89  [3]
  --- x --- x ---
  ```

Comment: I'll be happy solving the first problem (escaping \), the second can be solved with kind of a workaround. So if someone knows any way to print that char I'd appreciate.

I've already tried \textbackslash, \\, $\$, \@backslashchar and none worked.

Comment: It's about `@` in macro names: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: You could also try the [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) or the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) packages.

Answer (score 5):

There are many problems in your code. TeX is not C, and

```
\def\x#1
{
  ...
}
```

is *very* different from

```
\def\x#1{...}
```

Here is a way to produce your list

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@startloa{%
  \begin{listofabbrv}{SPMD}
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.loa}{}{\item[\null]}
  \end{listofabbrv}
  \newwrite\@loa
  \immediate\openout\@loa=\jobname.loa
}
\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}{\@startloa}

% abvr{abvr}{text}
\def\abvr#1#2{\immediate\write\@loa{\unexpanded{\item[#1]#2}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{listofabbrv}[1]{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
\listofabbreviations

\abvr{NULL}{/dev/null}

\end{document}
```

The `\newenvironment` line is just to have a `listofabbrv` environment.

Comment: Unless I missed something, `\provideenvironment` is an undefined control sequence.

Comment: @lockstep I keep forgetting it. :(